# maven directory not found in Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, deployment

I am doing auto deployment of Java Application using Maven and Jenkins, but it is getting failed.Here is the console output:

[image]

I have set the environment varaibles and also downloaded and configure all the required plugins. Need help to solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Please copy/paste messages instead of using images.

Secondly, the message said that you probably misconfigured the directory for the settings.xml. The settings.xml is usually in the directory  `.m2` in the user directory, but it can also be supplied from somewhere else.